# Verifying simple inequality involving FactorialPower function

Tags: special-functions, inequalities

It is obviously true that

```
FactorialPower[k, m] <= k^m
```

when `k` and `m` are both positive integers.

Is there anyway to verify this in Mathematica?

---

Note, initially I mistakenly used `Pochhammer` instead of `FactorialPower`

Comment: It is false in view of Pochhammer[k, m]/k^m /. {k -> 234, m -> 137} // N which produces $ 4.57254\times 10^{14}$.

Comment: Use `FindInstance` to find a counterexample: `FindInstance[{Pochhammer[k, m] > k^m, k > 0, m > 0, 
  Element[{m, k}, Integers]}, {k, m}]`

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon : The opposite inequality is Pochhammer[k, m] >= k^m.

Comment: @user64494 - Yes, but either will provide a counterexample.

Comment: `FactorialPower[k,1]==k^1`

Comment: Would you consider the result of `Assuming[m > 0, AsymptoticLessEqual[FactorialPower[k, m], k^m, k -> ∞]]` convincing?